# Accessing The Ref of a Component Passed Down as Props?

Tags: reactjs, ref, styled-components, react-props

I am passing down a styled component

```
const Text = styled.span`
   font-size: 10px
`

render(){
   <Test comp = {<Text innerRef={(ref)=>{this.ref=ref}}>Hello</Text>}/>
}
```

Inside of the `Test` component I want to access the `ref` of `Text` but I am having trouble doing so. Is this possible? I want to get access to the font-size value inside of `Test`. Thanks in advance for all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're passing a component as a prop to another component, React does not render it at all, and therefor you have no `ref`.

If your goal is to wrap `Text` in `Test`, the proper way to do so is passing it as a **child**. That way React will actually render the component, and will produce its `ref`.

```
const Text = styled.span`
   font-size: 10px
`

render(){
   <Test>
     <Text innerRef={ref => this.ref = ref}>Hello</Text>
   </Test>
}
```

If you want to access the `ref` in `Test`, you can do it via `this.props.children.ref`

**EDIT**

Since `styled-components` have their own prop for getting the `ref`, you need to use `React.createRef()` and access the `ref` via the props:

```
const Text = styled.span`
   font-size: 10px
`

class Test extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    // This is how you access the ref ;)
    console.log(this.props.children.props.innerRef.current);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='test'>{this.props.children}</div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <Test>
        <Text innerRef={React.createRef()}/>
      </Test>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how would i access the ref inside of Test component?

Comment: if i try to do

window.getComputedStyle(this.props.children[0].ref, null).getPropertyValue(property);

it doesnt work, meaning the ref isnt there.

Comment: even when i just log it, i get a string of the function

Comment: @Azimi Yes, you're right. I just tested it and updated my answer

Comment: So theres no way to access the ref before it mounts in the child component?

Comment: That's correct. The ref is only generated after the component is mounted.